# Galaxy S4 picking resource from drawable-sw360dp-hdpi instead of drawable-xxhdpi?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-drawable

I have following `drawable` folder inside my app.

```
drawable
drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-sw360dp-hdpi
drawable-sw480dp-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
```

Now S4 is `xxhdpi` device but it is picking resource from `drawable-sw360dp`-hdpi. In article in this url 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html. it is mentioned that it select folder on the basis of `highest-precedence qualifier` from table of qualifier.

Since some folders have `sw` qualifier it select those folder and eliminates other and S4 is picking resources from drawable-sw360dp-hdpi because S4 width is 360 dp and it matches that folder but S4 density is `xxhdpi`, it is ignoring density because `sw` qualifier is matching? So it prefer `sw` because it is top above `dpi` in table of qualifier?
Is it true that it is picking resource from folder on the basis of qualifier and not on the basis of denisty as drawable-xxhdpi matches exactly with S4.

So to make S4 pick correct resource do I need to change drawable-xxhdpi to drawable-sw360dp-xxhdpi.

Answer (score 0):

samsung S4 and sony xperiaz doesn't picks up from folder drawable-xxhdpi....!!!!

we made drawable-h900dp folder and corresponding to S4's height dpi equivalent 1920/2=960dpi.
since h900 says minimum height is 1800 it picked resourecs from it.

but those resourses got stretched by 2 times... odd behaviour

so we made it as drawable-h900dp-nodpi now resources are being taken and maintaining the original size.